# Combining longtable, booktabs, and xcolor in LaTex, layout problems

Tags: latex, longtable

I am trying to create a nice-looking table over multiple pages in LaTeX. For that, I am using longtable to divide the table in different pages of the document, booktabs to give it a nicer look, and xcolor to change the way the table looks.

It's a 3-columns table. I would like the header to be shaded in grey, and the rows to have alternating white/myblue shades.

The booktabs and xcolor layout worked nicely when I used `\begin{table}` combined with `\begin{tabular}` packages. However, since the table is too long for a single page, I changed to longtable. Now, neither booktabs options (`\toprule`, etc) nor xcolor (`\rowcolors`) work. Strangely, `\rowcolor` for the header now works. Since `\toprule` and `\midrule` from booktabs were not working, I regressed to using `\hline`.

The code I have right now is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,204,204}

\begin{document}


\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{llc}
\caption{Primer list for IRD-associated loci long-range PCRs}
\label{tab:ch3_1_LR_primers}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{myblue!15}
\hline



\rowcolor{gray!20}
\textbf{Text 1} & \textbf{Text sequence} & \textbf{Number}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\caption{continued from previous page} \\

\endhead


\endlastfoot

ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\

\end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

What do I need to change to have commands from both packages to work?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a couple of missing `\\`, misplaced `\rowcolours` and removing the unnecessary `\endlastfoot` one can make the code compilable. In theory you could now also replace the `\hline` with `\toprule` etc, but then you will face the problem that booktabs together with such zebra stripe tables will lead to white gaps, so you have to decide

- either use such zebra stripes together with `\hline`

or

- make a nice looking table with the booktab rules and abandon the colouring

(I strongly suggest the second approach)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,204,204}

\begin{document}

{
\small
\rowcolors{1}{white}{myblue!15}
\begin{longtable}{llc}
\caption{Primer list for IRD-associated loci long-range PCRs}
\label{tab:ch3_1_LR_primers}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!20}\textbf{Text 1} & \textbf{Text sequence} & \textbf{Number}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{continued from previous page} \\
\endhead
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\

\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```